# How to get standard deviation/standard error Beta diversity using adipart?

Tags: math, beta

I am using the function adipart in the vegan package to partition diversity across spatial scales. I would like to get the standard error and/or standard deviations for my measures of beta and alpha at different scales. Is there any way to retrieve this data?

Are there other ways to get measures of variations for alpha and beta diversity in additive partitioning framework?

Thank you,

Laura

Comment: please put your question in detail with some shareable code.

Comment: Could you please mention the programming language and/or environment you are using?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), take [the SO tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour), read about [how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/). Lastly learn how to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Spelling and grammar